# how to enable boost::posix::stream_descriptor on windows?

Tags: windows, boost-asio

I have a linux application that uses bluetooth. I must port it to windows. Since I knew that from the start I chose `boost` to replace `epoll`. Both windows and linux use BSD sockets for bluetooth. So all I need to do is initialize the file descriptor, put it into `boost::posix::stream_descriptor` and from that point forward I can use both `wait_read` and `wait_write`.

However, compiler says `boost::posix::stream_descriptor` is undefined. Can I enable it? I am using msys2 to both set up mingw64 toolchain and install boost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows equivalent, like [`windows::stream_handle`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__stream_handle.html).

Alternatively, you could opt to use a posix-compatible compiler like MinGW++ http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php

Comment: if only I knew how to fix error `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'boost::asio::windows::basic_overlapped_handle<>::native_handle_type'` in `source.assign(socket_fd)`.

Comment: How did you get the `socket_fd` in the first place? What compiler are you using?

Comment: compiler: mingw-64, winsock2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket.